# solve the inequation : $-|y| + x - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 -1} \geq 1$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I wanted to know, how to the following inequation

$-|y| + x - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 -1}  \geq 1$

I did $x-|y| \geq\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - 1} +1 \geq 0$ which gives $x \geq |y|$, what to do next...

any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You mean for what $(x,y)$ this holds ?
are they real or complex?

Comment: Hint: begin by considering that $x^2+y^2\geq 1$: then open the $|y|$, arriving at 2 inequalities

Comment: @Avitus would u mind writing an answer, i am not getting it

Comment: @Shobhit ok, I wrote an answer with some computations. You can also use a geometrical intepretation of the loci $x-y=0$, $x+y=0$ $x^2+y^2-1+0$...

Comment: thanks @avitas i have got the answer and also posted it, mind checking it.

Comment: I do it right now :)

Comment: @Shobhit You ask, you change the question, you answer!
First try to understand the answer then ask it here!

Comment: @Shobhit Take a look at [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/447960/revisions) You asked first for $0$ then after I answered your question, you changed it to $1$! :-D. Accepting our fault is hard, but it is good. Trust me!

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi MISTAKE ON MY SIDE ^_^ SORRY,

Comment: @ILUA :D + a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** The answer refers to the inequality in the *original* OP question.

We begin by considering only those $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ s.t. $x^2+y^2-1\geq 0$. If $y\geq 0$, then the given inequality is

$$x-y\geq \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}~(\geq 0),$$

while for $y<0$ one has

$$x+y\geq \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}~(\geq 0).$$

Now we can apply the second power to both sides of the inequalities, arriving at

$$2xy\leq 1 \cap y\geq 0 $$
$$2xy\geq-1 \cap y\leq 0$$

or

$$\{xy\leq \frac{1}{2} \cap y\geq 0\cap x^2+y^2-1\geq 0\}\cup \{-\frac{1}{2}\leq xy \cap y\leq 0\cap x^2+y^2-1 \geq 0\}. $$

**EDIT** We consider now the edited inequality $x-|y|\geq 1+ \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}$

Considering the inequality

$$x-|y|\geq 1+ \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}\geq 1+0 $$

we need to start imposing  $\{x-|y|\geq 1\}\cap \{x^2+y^2-1\geq 0\}$. Squaring both sides, we arrive at

$$-x|y|\geq  \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1},$$

which implies $-x|y|\geq 0$.

Considering the absolute value $|y|$and squaring we arrive at the inequalities

$$\{x-|y|\geq 1\}\cap \{x^2+y^2-1\geq 0\}\cap\{-x|y|\geq 0\}\cap\{y\geq 0\}\cap\{x^2y^2\geq x^2+y^2-1\},$$

and

$$\{x-|y|\geq 1\}\cap \{x^2+y^2-1\geq 0\}\cap\{-x|y|\geq 0\}\cap\{y\leq 0\}\cap\{x^2y^2\geq x^2+y^2-1\}.$$

In the first chain the condition $y\geq 0$ (which implies $|y|=y$) gives

$$\{x-y\geq 1\}\cap \{x^2+y^2-1\geq 0\}\cap\{-x|y|\geq 0\}\cap\{y\geq 0\}\cap\{x^2y^2\geq x^2+y^2-1\}=\{x-y\geq 1\}\cap \{x^2+y^2-1\geq 0\}\cap\{x\leq 0\}\cap\{x^2y^2\geq x^2+y^2-1\}.$$

In the second chain the inequality $y\leq 0$ (which implies $|y|=-y$) gives

$$\{x-|y|\geq 1\}\cap \{x^2+y^2-1\geq 0\}\cap\{-x|y|\geq 0\}\cap\{y\leq 0\}\cap\{x^2y^2\geq x^2+y^2-1\}=\{x+y\geq 1\}\cap \{x^2+y^2-1\geq 0\}\cap\{x\leq 0\}\cap\{x^2y^2\geq x^2+y^2-1\},$$

instead.

In summary, the solutions $(x,y)$ to the original inequality are given by

$$\left(\{x-y\geq 1\}\cap \{x^2+y^2-1\geq 0\}\cap\{x\leq 0\}\cap\{x^2y^2\geq x^2+y^2-1\}\right) \cup \left(\{x+y\geq 1\}\cap \{x^2+y^2-1\geq 0\}\cap\{x\leq 0\}\cap\{x^2y^2\geq x^2+y^2-1\}\right)$$

Comment: @Avitas the statement i nur answer -x|y| (>,=)0, implies that one or both of x,y is zero, but that is not possible as              x^2 + y^2 - 1 (>,=)0. therefore one of them is zero, x cannot be zero or it will contradict x(>,=)|y| , therefore y=0, which gives x =(+1,-1) but x (>,=)|y|, therefore the only admissible answer is (x,y) = (1,0).notify me if i am wrong

Comment: $-x|y|\geq 0$ is equivalent to $-x|y|=0$ $or$ $-x|y|>0$. In your statement in your comment you are forgetting the $-x|y|>0$ inequality.

Comment: @Avitas -x|y| (>,=) sqrt(x^2 +y^2 -1) (>,=)0.   or, -x|y| (>,=)0, the rest follows.

Comment: (btw my nickname is AvitUs) "or" is wrong. $-x|y|\geq \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}\Rightarrow -x|y|\geq 0 \cap x^2+y^2-1\geq 0 \cap-x|y|\geq \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1} $, which is different from your assertion. The first 2 inequalities are necessary to go on with the analysis, while the 3rd is the one to be further simplified.

Comment: nice nickname(AvitUs), look here,  x (>,=) |y| and |y| is obviously (>,=)0 therefore x|y| (>,=)0 and -x|y|(<,=)0 also we are getting  -x|y| (>,=) sqrt(x^2 + y^2 -1) . since L.H.S is non positive and R.H.S is non negative therefore the only possibility is when both side are zero. ^_^ AvitUs, i didn't know Avitus sorry for Avitas.am i wrong in my answer,notify.

Comment: Ok, let us put it this way, if I cannot convince you :) : $(x,y)=(1,0)$(your first comment) cannot be a solution because does not satisfy $-x|y|\geq 0$. On the other way, **for example**  all points $(-x_0,1)$ with $x_0\geq 0$ satisfy $-x|y|\geq \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}$. No problem with the nickname!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9732/discussion-between-shobhit-and-avitus)

Answer (score 0):

going to what @Avitas suggest,

squaring both sides of

> $x-|y| \geq  1 + \sqrt{x^2 +y^2 -1}$

we get

> $x^2+y^2-2x|y| \geq 1 +x^2 +y^2 -1 +2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 -1}$

or,

> $-x|y|\geq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 -1}$

since

> $x \geq |y| \geq 0$

, then L.H.S of is non positive and R.H.S of is non negative.

therefore inequality is satisfied when both sides are zero.

x|y|=0 implies x=0 or y=0 and

> $x^2 + y^2 =1$

solving we get,

> $(x,y)\equiv(1,0)$

Comment: It is difficult to read the math. You can learn how to format math on this site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: "therefore inequality is satisfied when both sides are zero" does not convince me...until that sentence I think that it is correct. You arrive at  $-x|y|\geq \sqrt{...}$: you need to "open" the absolute value $|y|$ and consider 2 different inequalities (like in my answer).

Comment: i have edited it check now.

Comment: I do not agree: I modify my answer to include your computations. Please, have a look a them after my edit.